# Why apache poi SSPerformanceTest fails on my machine with GC overhead limit error even with the inputs mentioned with the FAQ (XSSF 50000 50 1)

Tags: java, excel, apache, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I want to create excel file with apache poi, but I have error GC overhead limit exceeded.
On the FAQ apache poi I read: (http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109)

> Apache POI ships with a few programs and a few example programs, which can be used to do some basic performance checks. For testing file generation, the class to use is in the examples package, SSPerformanceTest. Run SSPerformanceTest with arguments of the writing type (HSSF, XSSF or SXSSF), the number rows, the number of columns, and if the file should be saved. If you can't run that with 50,000 rows and 50 columns in all of HSSF, XSSF and SXSSF in under 3 seconds (ideally a lot less!), the problem is with your environment.

I run test with parameters XSSF 50000 rows, 50 columns, 1 (create file) and have error GC overhead limit. Why? I tried to increse memory, but it isn't work for me.

I use YourKit Java Profiler for search reason. And error was in cell.setCellValue when row = 2036.

I don't know why test from FAQ didn't work for me.
Also I test for SXSSF and test expanded for 11 seconds, not for 3 seconds.
I read that:

> Try setting each object equal to 
>   null at the very end of the loop, before it loops back to the top. 
>   When you create an object be it a row, cell or sheet you need to explicitly destroy them when finished with.
>   The system does not do this automatically.
>   If this is not carried out it can lead to unwanted storage usage and JAVA leaks.

It isn't work.
I want to know how resolved this problem? What's wrong with apache poi SSPerformanceTest which recommended in FAQ? What reason of this error?